# Populating nested object data in table in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have this component which receives data now I want to populate Item and subItems in same row
but subItems are nested inside Item. Is there a way to do this.

```
return (
    <div className="table">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Time</th>
          <th>open</th>
          <th>high</th>
          <th>low</th>
          <th>close</th>
          <th>volume</th>
        </tr>
        {data &&
          Object.keys(data).map((item, index) => {
            <td>{item}</td>;

            Object.keys(data[item]).map((subitem, ind) => {
              return <td>{data[item][subitem]}</td>;
            });
          })}
      </table>
    </div>
  );
```

Nothing gets displayed except for the table headings

Comment: So what is the problem? do you get any errors or what is it you wanna fix?

Comment: You just missed wrapping `{}` for subitems.

Comment: attach what you desire.

Comment: My data is not displayed as if it does not exist